# Duda uso de registros ENSAMBLADOR

Tags: ensamblador, mips32

¿Cual es la diferencia entre usar los registros `T`, los registros `A`, los registros `S` (o `SB`) o los registros `V` en lenguaje ensamblador? (concretamente en el MARS MIPS)

Answer (score 2):

Por convenio, de los 32 registros de la CPU, se utilizarían "**según normas de buen uso**"  para lo siguiente:

- `zero` Ocupa la posición 0 y es una **constante con valor 0.**
- `at`  Ocupa la posición 1 y es **Temporal para el ensamblador.**
- `v0` a `v1` Ocupan la posición 2 a 3 y se utilizan para **Valores devueltos en funciones.**
- **`a0` a `a3`** Ocupan la posición 4 a 7 y se utilizan para **argumentos en funciones.**
- **`t0` a `t7`** Ocupan la posición 8 a 15 y se utilizan para **Temporales.**
- **`s0` a `s7`** Ocupan la posición 16 a 23 y se utilizan para **Temporales salvados (Son preservados).**
- **`t8` a `79`** Ocupan la posición 24 a 25 y se utilizan para **Temporales.**
- `k0` a `k1` Ocupan la posición 26 a 27 y están **reservados para kernel.**
- `gp` Ocupa la posición 28 y es un **puntero global.**
- `sp` Ocupa la posición 29 y es un **puntero de pila.**
- `fp` Ocupa la posición 30 y es un **puntero de marco.**
- `ra` Ocupa la posición 31 y es un **puntero de retorno.**